# Understanding component props in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying out vuejs by following along with the laracasts series of webcasts on this. In https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vue-step-by-step/episodes/8, Jeffery Way discusses custom components. I have the following code based on his screencast:

```
    <div id="app">
        <tasks list="tasks"></tasks>
    </div>

    <template id="tasks-template">
        <ul>
            <li :class="{'completed' : task.c}" @click = "task.c = ! task.c"  v-for ="task in tasks">{{task.t}}</li>

        </ul>

    </template>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.12/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    vue.component('tasks', {
    template: '#tasks-template',

    props:['list'] // why not props:['tasks'] ??

    });

    new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        tasks: [
            {t: 'go to doctor', c: false},
            {t: 'go to work', c: false},
            {t: 'go to store', c: true}
        ]

    }
```

In this he discusses setting the props as follows:

```
    props:['list']
```

Why is it not

```
props:['tasks'] ?
```

In http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props it states:

> Every component instance has its own isolated scope. This means you cannot (and should not) directly reference parent data in a child component’s template. Data can be passed down to child components using props.A “prop” is a field on a component’s data that is expected to be passed down from its parent component. A child component needs to explicitly declare the props it expects to receive using the props option:

How does the component know to associate the tasks array with list? Also in this case I assume child = component and parent = the vue instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The property on your component is called `list` and the value passed to it is `tasks`.

Let's see this. First you have your main Vue instance *attached* (mounted) to the element with identifier `#app`. So this is your starting point.

```
<div id="app">
    <tasks list="tasks"></tasks>
</div>
```

inside of your div you have a `<tasks>` tag. That tag correspond to a child component, so

> child = component and parent = the vue instance

Is correct. The `<tasks>` component is an extension of the Vue class, which has only a property declared like `list`. The important thing here are scopes. Notice that the `list` property belongs to the tasks components, and has no value in its declaration, and the value passed to it on the template (everything inside the `#app` div) belongs to the parent Vue instance (declared on the `data` of the Vue instance). So why don't `props:['tasks']`? **Because the `<tasks>` component has no `tasks` data or property**. if you actually declared the property like tasks, you would have to write your template as follows

```
<div id="app">
    <tasks tasks="tasks"></tasks>
</div>
```

that would be a litle confusing. So thats why the prop is `list` and because of the declaration `list="tasks"` is that the component know that the list property has the value of the parent tasks array.

Comment: How does the data: tasks[] array from the view instance become available for binding to list="tasks" ? My guess, after reading what you wrote is that it becomes available within the scope of the view instance element - i.e. <div id="app"></div>

Comment: Everything inside `#app` div is availaible from the main Vue instance. What happens is that the main vue instance has access to the component, and the component, as every vue instance always expose whats inside thier `data` and `props`. So, the `list` property belongs to the component, but is reachable to the main instance through the component

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Now Vuejs 2.x is released. You can use v-bind to dynamically bind the props. You also can refer to https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props

One thing you need to pay attention is that HTML attributes are case-insensitive, so when using non-string templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-case (hyphen-delimited) equivalents. Eg

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  // camelCase in JavaScript
  props: ['myMessage'],
  template: '<span>{{ myMessage }}</span>'
})
```

```html
<!-- kebab-case in HTML -->
<child my-message="hello!"></child>
```

So your sample can change to below

```js
    <div id="app">
        <tasks v-bind:list="tasks"></tasks>
    </div>

    <template id="tasks-template">
        <ul>
            <li :class="{'completed' : task.c}" @click = "task.c = ! task.c"  v-for ="task in tasks">{{task.t}}</li>

        </ul>

    </template>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.3/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    vue.component('tasks', {
    template: '#tasks-template',

    props:['list'] // why not props:['tasks'] ??

    });

    new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        tasks: [
            {t: 'go to doctor', c: false},
            {t: 'go to work', c: false},
            {t: 'go to store', c: true}
        ]

    }
```